# Invalid argument: Instance of 'DateTime'

Tags: android, flutter, datetime

I am working on a Flutter plugin, and I would like to pass from my `dart` file Native Android a `DateTime` parameter.

The implementation is simple:

**Dart**

```
  Future<bool?> getDate(DateTime localTime) async {
      return         _dateChannel.invokeMethod<bool>('my_method_channel',
          {'localTime': localTime});
  }
```

**Java**

```
if (methodCall.method.equals("my_method_channel")) {
            Date localTime = methodCall.argument("localTime");

            System.out.println(
                    "TEST |  Estimated localTime | " + localTime);

            result.success(true);
}
```

but I am getting the following error

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'DateTime'

**Note** that this is a simplication of my implementation. I understand that I could get `localTIme` natively but that's not what I am looking for.

Explanation of the current situation and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data type Date/Datetime is not supported for platform channel. You should pass an argument as String type and then parse it in Java code.

https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-java-tab#codec

Comment: Or convert it to millis since the epoch.

Comment: Indeed.

```
_dateChannel.invokeMethod<bool>('my_method_channel',
          {'localTime': localTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
``` solved the issue